# Using update-rc.d

Tags: ubuntu, debian

As per [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20357/how-can-i-make-a-script-in-etc-init-d-start-at-boot), I'd like to start a `/etc/init.d` script on boot. I have the following script comments:

```
# Startup script for Wowza Media Server
#
# chkconfig: - 80 20
# description: Wowza Media Server is a media server
#
#### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          WowzaMediaServer
# Required-Start:    $syslog $time $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $syslog $time $local_fs $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      S 0 1 2 6
# Short-Description: Wowza Media Server 3 Init Script
# Description:       Wowza Media Server 3 Init Script
### END INIT INFO
```

I understand that for Debian and Ubuntu systems, rather than using `chkconfig`, I need to use `update-rc.d`. I've done this in the past, but it seems that `update-rc.d` just links the script to all runlevels. Is this really the case?

I need this script to only run when starting after networking is up; I'm running a script that needs to `curl` a URL in order to determine the public DNS name of the host (EC2). How can I add this script to auto-start using `update-rc.d` in the way I'm looking to do it?

Comment: there's also nice sysv-rc-conf tool available for apt-get.

Comment: In what way are you dissatisfied with what `update-rc.d` does? Yes, it links the script to all (normal) runlevels, so what?

Comment: If you really want it to run "after networking is up" you could just add it to `/etc/network/if-up.d/`

Comment: @Gilles, sorry, I guess I don't really understand what runlevels are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take into account that Debian and Ubuntu only use runlevels 0, 1, 2, 6, and the default graphical multiuser runlevel is 2.

Ubuntu has the added complication of [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) managing the event based services startup process, but old `init.d` script are still supported.

I think that the following command should work

```
update-rc.d script-base-name defaults
```

because, as you can see with the `-n` (dry run) option, it creates links whose names begin with `S20` in runlevels 2, 3, 4, 5, the only meaningful being the 2, and I suppose the network is already started when the script will be executed.

If you want to be sure, you can add a greater sequence number, as in

```
update-rc.d script-base-name defaults 99
```

so that the links will be created with the `S99` prefix, assuring the service is the last to be run.

Comment: Runlevels 3, 4 and 5 exist, and you can customize them. It's just that by default, they are set up identically to runlevel 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

`update-rc.d wowza start 99 2 3 4 5 .`