# How do I create a service for a shell script so I can start and stop it like a daemon?

Tags: shell-script, centos, cron, services, sysvinit

I'm using CentOS 7 what my aim is to create a cron for every five seconds but as I researched we can use cron only for a minute so what I am doing now is I have created a shell file.
**hit.sh**

```
while sleep 5; do curl http://localhost/test.php; done
```

but I have hit it manually through right clicking it.

What I want is to create a service for that file so that i can start and stop it automatically.

I found the [script to create a service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20357/how-can-i-make-a-script-in-etc-init-d-start-at-boot)

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: Description comes here....

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

start() {
    # code to start app comes here 
    # example: daemon program_name &
}

stop() {
    # code to stop app comes here 
    # example: killproc program_name
}

case "$1" in 
    start)
       start
       ;;
    stop)
       stop
       ;;
    restart)
       stop
       start
       ;;
    status)
       # code to check status of app comes here 
       # example: status program_name
       ;;
    *)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

But I don't know what to write in start or stop methods I tried placing the same content of hit.sh in `start(){}` but it gave error for `}` in stop method.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Users trying to run a script as a daemon on a modern system should be using `systemd`:

```
[Unit]
Description=hit service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/hit.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save this as `/etc/systemd/system/hit.service`, and then you will be able to start/stop/enable/disable it with `systemctl start hit`, etc.

### Old answer from 2015:

If you'd like to reuse your code sample, it could look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in 
start)
   /path/to/hit.sh &
   echo $!>/var/run/hit.pid
   ;;
stop)
   kill `cat /var/run/hit.pid`
   rm /var/run/hit.pid
   ;;
restart)
   $0 stop
   $0 start
   ;;
status)
   if [ -e /var/run/hit.pid ]; then
      echo hit.sh is running, pid=`cat /var/run/hit.pid`
   else
      echo hit.sh is NOT running
      exit 1
   fi
   ;;
*)
   echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

Naturally, the script you want to be executed as a service should go to e.g. `/usr/local/bin/hit.sh`, and the above code should go to `/etc/init.d/hitservice`.

For each runlevel which needs this service running, you will need to create a respective symlink. For example, a symlink named `/etc/init.d/rc5.d/S99hitservice` will start the service for runlevel 5. Of course, you can still start and stop it manually via `service hitservice start`/`service hitservice stop`

Comment: Does the file need a suffix like: hitservice.service?
After this: Failed to start backupservice.service: Unit not found. On CentOS 7 so why is this suggested as answer

Comment: @Code.IT Note that the OP wanted a SystemV script, not a `systemd` script, thus no suffix is needed. You should be able to run old scripts with `systemd` just fine though. Have you tried `systemctl enable hitservice`?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: This script doesn't prevent multiple instances nor stop all multiple instances created, the _pidfile_ stores only the last pid's spawned process.

Comment: What would be the proper way to pipe the stdout/stderr to /var/log? just `hit.sh > /var/log/hit.log 2>&1 &`?

Comment: @E.S. The proper way would be to use systemd's new-style daemons, which have STDOUT/STDERR connected to systemd-journald by default. For legacy SysV daemons redirection to a file could be good enough.

Comment: @Luciano Yeah, this is only good enough if you don't try to start the service twice. And if you do, you need to consider many more things like race conditions and PID reuse, which were some of the reasons systemd was implemented.

Comment: Actually, the service file should go to `/etc/systemd/system` and not `/etc/init.d/`

Comment: @MoDzeus This is not a service file but a SysV script. It also doesn't need a `.service` extension and cannot be started with `systemctl`.

Answer (score 39):

I believe CentOS 7 and above uses systemd. If that is the case for your system, try the following:

1. Place the script commands you wish to run in `/usr/bin/myscript`.
2. Remember to make the script executable with `chmod +x`.
3. Create the following file:

**/etc/systemd/system/my.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myscript

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4. Reload all systemd service files: `systemctl daemon-reload`
5. Check that it is working by starting the service with `systemctl start my`.

**Bonus:**

For testing the systemd service, it is possible to launch a tmux environment with two window panes, where the top window monitors the output from the script (`stdout` and `stderr`) and the bottom window can be used for restarting services. This requires `tmux` to be installed, then simply:

```
tmux new-session \; select-layout even-horizontal \; split-window -v journalctl -o cat --since=@$(date +%s) -f -u my \; rotate-window \; set -g status-bg colour0 \; set -g status-fg colour9 \; attach
```

Then restart the service with:

```
systemctl restart my
```

Exit `tmux` with `ctrl-d` and then `ctrl-c`.

Once you're happy with the script and service file, change

```
Type=forking
```

into

```
Type=simple
```

Done.

Comment: thanks for replying I tried you solution but the service is not starting can you look at my question I added the details

Comment: I think it will work if your script doesn't fail, but returns error code 0.

Comment: Now I like systemd!

Comment: systemctl start backupdirectories ->
Failed to start backupdirectories.service: Unit not found.

Comment: Code.IT, well, where did you place it?

Comment: Can we symlink the scripts to `/usr/bin/` or do we have to actually put them there?

Comment: The script can be placed anywhere, as long as the systemd service can access and execute it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `Type=forking`. Chances are the asker would need `Type=simple` but in general forking is not recommended: http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/daemon.html#Writing%20Systemd%20Unit%20Files. People have been taking their old init scripts and wrapping them in `systemd` so that the startup of their service goes `systemd(init-script(service))`. However `systemd` is a replacement for init scripts, so you should be calling the service directly with `systemd` so that it looks like `systemd(service)`.

Comment: `Type=forking` has better logging for simple scripts, since it not only shows when the script is starting (`Starting My Script...`) but also when it is done running (`Started My Script.`).

Answer (score 4):

This is my script as a service:

```
[Unit]
Description=To change In test buffer
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/test.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at fpm. It is a tool that will create init scripts for you. Works on many platforms (systemd, upstart, ect..)

https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm

Answer (score 2):

The below code block can be very helpful to convert the linux scripts into service

1. Login into the server with root access
2. Create the following **systemd** unit file for the required service & change permissions per below

```
touch /lib/systemd/system/test.service
chmod 664 /lib/systemd/system/test.service
```

3. Add the following content into the **systemd** unit file to define the service

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Service
After=network.target
 
[Service]
Type=forking
User=#username
PIDFile=#test.pid_path
ExecStart=#startup_script_path
ExecStop=#shutdown_script_path
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4. Enable it as a service

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable test.service
```

5. Use below commands to start, stop, status & restart

```
systemctl start test.service
systemctl stop test.service
systemctl status test.service
systemctl restart test.service
```

Answer (score 0):

See **Bash Service Manager** project: https://github.com/reduardo7/bash-service-manager

### Implementation example

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export PID_FILE_PATH="/tmp/my-service.pid"
export LOG_FILE_PATH="/tmp/my-service.log"
export LOG_ERROR_FILE_PATH="/tmp/my-service.error.log"

. ./services.sh

run-script() {
  local action="$1" # Action

  while true; do
    echo "@@@ Running action '${action}'"
    echo foo
    echo bar >&2

    [ "$action" = "run" ] && return 0
    sleep 5
    [ "$action" = "debug" ] && exit 25
  done
}

before-start() {
  local action="$1" # Action

  echo "* Starting with $action"
}

after-finish() {
  local action="$1" # Action
  local serviceExitCode=$2 # Service exit code

  echo "* Finish with $action. Exit code: $serviceExitCode"
}

action="$1"
serviceName="Example Service"

serviceMenu "$action" "$serviceName" run-script "$workDir" before-start after-finish
```

### Usage example

```
$ ./example-service
# Actions: [start|stop|restart|status|run|debug|tail(-[log|error])]

$ ./example-service start
# Starting Example Service service...

$ ./example-service status
# Serive Example Service is runnig with PID 5599

$ ./example-service stop
# Stopping Example Service...

$ ./example-service status
# Service Example Service is not running
```