# How to make a service that starts on boot in CentOS?

Tags: centos, startup, services

When I boot my CentOS box, the `httpd` service starts automatically. How do I make a custom service that does the same thing? I have a program I use for mining, and I don't want to need to run `./miner` every time I boot the machine.

Comment: what version of CentOS are you using?

Comment: I'm using CentOs 7.1 server.

Comment: Are you sure that your miner program doesn't already have a script in /etc/init.d/ ?

Comment: Centos 7.1 -> `systemd`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you are using CentOS 7.x, create a Unit. `vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/miner.service` as `root` and put the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=miner

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/miner

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You could add `ExecStop=` and `ExecReload=` options if there are specific arguments used to close or reload services.

After that, you just need to `systemctl enable miner.service` to make it start on each boot.

**Related Stuff:**

- [Writing basic systemd service files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15348/writing-basic-systemd-service-files)
- [man: systemd.service — Service unit configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

Comment: On my CentOS 7 box, I got a "command not found" when running "systemd enable miner.service".  So I had to run "systemctl enable miner.service" instead.

Comment: `systemctl`. My fault. Fixing it :)

Comment: PSA: If, like me, you Googled your way here looking for how to do this in CentOS 6, you'll notice you don't have the `systemd` folder. What you want is the `chkconfig` tool, mentioned in M4rty's answer and further explained here: https://geekflare.com/how-to-auto-start-services-on-boot-in-linux/

Comment: @JustinMorgan, that's right. CentOS 6 does not use `systemd` as init or service manager system. One quick hack to it would be start this software using the `/etc/rc.local` script instead of creating a service start script...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the miner program provider you might have the associated service already declared.

On centOS you can check :

```
# chkconfig --list
```

and if you see your program you can tell the system to run it automaticly at boot time

```
# chkconfig postgresql on
```

If you don't find any result you can create your own dummy script using a template for example :

> [How do I create a service for a shell script so I can start and stop it like a daemon?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236084/how-do-i-create-a-service-for-a-shell-script-so-i-can-start-and-stop-it-like-a-d)

then put it in /etc/init.d/ and chmod +x it

You should be able to manage you miner application as a service with all the advantages that comes with it

Comment: Link to documentation for using `chkconfig`: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-services-chkconfig.html

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to run the command on boot, trying to make an actual service isn't really required. The simplest thing to do is to drop `. /path/to/miner` in /etc/rc.d/rc.local. This file is a script that is run on every boot (and make sure rc.local is executable), so your command will run when the server starts up.

If you need it to actually be handled as a service though, the best way to do that will depend on whether you're using CentOS 7 or 5/6.

edit: forgot to mention, this will be executed as root, so if you need it run as a non-root user, use instead `su - username -c /path/to/miner`