# How can I make a script in /etc/init.d?

Tags: linux, bash, services

I'm trying to make my nodejs app a linux service. I found the link below on the stackexchange and created a script under the /etc/init.d folder.

[How can I make a script in /etc/init.d start at boot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20357/how-can-i-make-a-script-in-etc-init-d-start-at-boot)

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: Description comes here....

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

start() {
    # code to start app comes here 
    # example: daemon program_name &
    /usr/bin/node /home/myapp/index.js
}

stop() {
    # code to stop app comes here 
    # example: killproc program_name
}

case "$1" in 
    start)
       start
       ;;
    stop)
       stop
       ;;
    restart)
       stop
       start
       ;;
    status)
       # code to check status of app comes here 
       # example: status program_name
       ;;
    *)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac
```

I'm getting this error when I try to run the script.

```
$ service myapp start
/etc/init.d/myapp: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/etc/init.d/myapp: line 17: `}'
```

I can successfully run the nodejs app manually. Something is wrong with my service. I cannot use systemctl so please do not recommend it.

I want to make this nodejs app a linux service that can be controlled like httpd,ftpd.

Answer (score 2):

Your stop() function has no content.   Add some content, even if it's just running `/bin/true` (or maybe `killproc /usr/bin/node` ?) and it'll happily get past this error.

Example:

```
$ a() {
> echo foo
> }
$ b() {
> # comment
> }
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
$ b() {
> /bin/true
> }
$
```

Comment: The "official dummy command" is `:`