# Why my Linux service is starting and stopping at the same time?

Tags: centos, reboot, aws

I have one CentOS based Amazon Linux AMI and I was trying to setup custom service, in which a small bash script (which creates a dummy file in a particular location) will be called on boot.

I followed this tutorial https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20361 and created a custom service script `myscript` like below, and copied it into `/etc/init.d folder` with 777 permission and `root` as the owner;

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: Description comes here....

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

start() {
      echo -n "Starting myscript... "
      su user
      touch /data/startfile
      return 0
}

stop() {
      echo -n "Stopping myscript... "
      su user
      touch /data/stopfile
      return 0
}

case "$1" in 
    start)
       start
       ;;
    stop)
       stop
       ;;
    restart)
       stop
       start
       ;;
    status)
       ;;
    *)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

After rebooting the machine, when I checked `/data/` directory, I can see two files `startfile` as well as `stopfile`. If the service is starting automatically, `startfile` is expectable, but I wonder about `stopfile`. Can somebody please explain why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: The Stackexchange thread that you followed to create the service is nine years old. Centos 7 adopted systemd in 2015, and Centos 6 is obsolete now. You should not use init scripts but learn how to create a systemd service (very simple example: https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019672). Apart from that, I agree that you should check the timestamps of the two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initscript would have been called when you asked the system to reboot: that’s probably when the `stopfile` was created.

The `startfile` would have been created as expected during system boot.

Checking the timestamps on the files should allow you to confirm this: `stopfile` should be timestamped between the time you asked for the reboot and the time the system actually rebooted, and `startfile` should be timestamps after the system started booting again.