# For automatic startup is it enough to copy script to /etc/rc.d folders?

Tags: linux, rhel, sysvinit, rc

we have installed some tool on RedHat linux 8.5 which comes with a README file that explains steps we should do, in order to enable automatic startup:

- Copy the  'accurev' script to the /etc/rc.d/init.d/

`cp /opt/accurev/extras/unix/accurev /etc/rc.d/init.d/`

- make links as follows

  `ln -s /etc/rc.d/init.d/accurev /etc/rc.d/rc0.d/K35accurev`

  `ln -s /etc/rc.d/init.d/accurev /etc/rc.d/rc1.d/K35accurev`

  `ln -s /etc/rc.d/init.d/accurev /etc/rc.d/rc2.d/S77accurev`

  `ln -s /etc/rc.d/init.d/accurev /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S77accurev`

  `ln -s /etc/rc.d/init.d/accurev /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/S77accurev`

  `ln -s /etc/rc.d/init.d/accurev /etc/rc.d/rc6.d/K35accurev`

README file does not contain any further instructions.
Since this is a production server I cannot test this properly, unfortunately.
Will this be enough to have the script started upon the reboot?
I was searching the similar topics like [How can I make a script in /etc/init.d start at boot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20357/how-can-i-make-a-script-in-etc-init-d-start-at-boot) and they mention the `chkconfig` tool which this README instruction does not mention, so I just wanted to be sure if I covered all the steps.
I couldn't find any instruction related to `/etc/rc.d` without mentioned `chkconfig` tool

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks good to me, but please check with other services that you have running, whether 77 is the correct order for starting and 35 is good for stopping. The tool vendor does not know when dependencies are initialized.

Comment: @Philippos thanks Philippos, can you please give me a hint how I could check the current list and order of other services? Thanks!!!

Comment: At first you **must** be certain about your init system. You tagged sysvinit and rc, a bit of a surprise to me since I thought RHEL 8 amongst systemd-ers. Second, you **must** know what these services demand (in terms of other services already running (to be started before)) and vice-versa, what other services you launch that would depend on these services already running)

Comment: Simply do `ls -l /etc/rc.d/rc5.d` for runlevel 5. The scripts (links to scripts) get executed in the order defined by their name. If `accurev` is depending on some other startup item with a higher `S`-number, it will fail,

Comment: Thanks a lot. How did you know that 35 corresponds to stopping? :)

Comment: REL 8 uses `systemd` for startup and rc scripts are certainly legacy. I would be leery of a vendor that is still shipping an rc script, especially one that does not support using `chkconfig add accurev` to automatically create the symlinks.